# Why angular cdk autofill does not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, angular, autofill

Enter the following link to try the example of (cdkAutofill): https://stackblitz.com/angular/rekpyvoxyqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftext-field-autofill-directive-example.html

**Chrome:** Fill fields and submit, clean 'First name' field value and then click into same field to autofill value, when the suggested value is selected, the value is updated successful, appear `Autofilled!` label.

[image]

**Firefox:** Do the same process above, but the `Autofilled!` label never appears.

This problem is old: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950510

After reviewing various forums and discussions, I find some solutions such as:

- https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d462fc2bf761a10c9fca60eb634f6977
- https://github.com/iamJoeTaylor/vanilla-autofill-event/blob/0787bdaf5a945ed716d113e144e8d51d04254947/src/autofill-event.js#L73

The main question is: **why does it only happen in Firefox? and how to fix it?**